# Story where a guy gets an email where if he agrees to go out and buy specific computers and store them in the attic then he'll get paid lots of money

Tags: identification-request

I was talking with someone today and it reminded me of a story I read over 20 years ago. I can't remember if it was stand-alone or a short story. I know I read the book before the year 2000, so anything after is out.

What I can remember is some guy who I recall being young or barely an adult gets an email where if he agrees to go out and buy specific computers and store them in the attic then he will get paid lots of money. Guy doesn't believe it at first until his bank balance got a large deposit. So he starts going out to fulfill the requests being made of him.

I had the title Finders Keeps by Emily Rodda floating around in my head with this, except it doesn't seem to be a short story collection and the back cover isn't this story.

Yes, I tried entering this into google, but "computer" gives me too many results that are clearly not this.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the story? Did you find out who the email and the money was from, and what they wanted the computers for? Was it a sci-fi or fantasy or mystery story?

Comment: @user14111 I dont remember him ever finding out WHY he was doing it (I always suspected it was himself from the future). Id say it was more sci-fi than mystery, didnt really read many mystery then or now.

Comment: It feels like some sort of time-traveler exploit, whether preserving technology against some apocalypse (maybe technology-forbidding by society) or preserving specific "vintage systems" to be sold as antiques.